# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function on array

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get data from the ID which I am receiving from the GET method. I am also receiving two parameters from the GET method, however, if I run my code it throws the error.

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProfileById() on array

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require '../config/init.php';
require 'inc/header.php';

require CLASS_PATH.'profile.php';
$profile = new Profile();


      if(isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['act']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['act'])){
      $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
      $action = $_GET['act'];


      if($action != substr(md5("edit_profile-".$id.$session->getSessionByKey('session_token')), 3, 15)){
          $_SESSION['error'] = "Token mismatch.";
          @header('location: profile');
          exit;
      }


      $profile_info = $profile->getProfileById($id);
```

And here is my code in class Profile:

```
class Profile extends Database
{
    public function __construct(){
        Database::__construct();
        $this->table('profile');
    }
        public function getProfileById($id){
        $args = array(
            'where' => array(
                'id' => $id
            ),
        );
        return $this->select($args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to pass $id parameter in function.

```
  $profile_info = $profile->getProfileById($id);
```

Also define parameter like this.

```
public function getProfileById($id = ""){
    Your code here
}
```

Comment: I passed $id parameter and also I tried your second suggestion but I received the same error. The same function getProfileById is working in other two files.

Comment: Can you please check what you pass in $id?

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass value into the function just pass variable and change line :

```
 $profile_info = $profile->getProfileById();
```

to

```
 $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
 $profile_info = $profile->getProfileById($id);
```

> Pass $id variable into the function then error is not showing

Comment: I passed the parameter but also it gave the same error. Moreover, the same function is giving me a result in another page.